# Query with quotes not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, request

I am sending a Query string like:-

```
String query = "select * from table where id = 12345 or id like '___1435'";
```

in php code:-

```
$phone     = $_REQUEST['data1'];
$result = mysql_query($phone);
    return $result;
```

through android but it is not working.
But a query like:-

```
String query = "select * from table where id = 12345 or id = 21435";
```

is working.

I also tried:-

```
$phone     = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['data1']);
$result = mysql_query($phone);
    return $result;
```

What could be the problem.
Most probably it is related to the quotes I am using in String.
How can I overcome this ?

Thank You!

Comment: You need to escape the underscores. Underscores have a special utility in SQL. Do underscores exist in your DB?

Comment: I am just using underscore as wildcard

Comment: same query is even working from a HTML form

Comment: `String query = "select * from table where id = 12345 or id like '___1435'";` this works from a HTML form but not in android, is this what you say?

Comment: I am using UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

A `LIKE` query needs percentage signs to signify a wild card, which I assume you are trying:

`id like '%___1435%'`

If you don't want this wildcard behaviour then you could just remove the like

`id = '___1435'`

Comment: FWIW, SQL pattern matching enables you to use `_` to match any single character and `%` to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters).

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you're attempting to perform a string comparison on an integer field. Try casting your ID field as a CHAR first, like this:

```
select * from table where id = 12345 or CAST(id as CHAR) like '___1435'
```

Edit: It's going to be a guessing game unless you can a) post some error logs or b) post your MySQL query log (to see the actual query executing), which you can enable by turning on the General Query Log for your installation. Since it looks like you're accepting your query string via POST, if the string has been encoded in any way (ie url encoding), it'll affect your query if not properly decoded first.

A better and more secure approach would be to create a specific web service that accepts the ID to query, which you can pass into a prepared statement server side. It's better practice anyway so your system isn't vulnerable to wide open queries from a client.

Comment: @HaigBedrosian : I don't think he has 125 reputation yet to downvote. :P

Comment: Good point! I know there's a lot of funny business that goes on but down voting legitimate answers that are aimed at helping a poster arrive at a solution to their problem is very counter-productive. It does not encourage further participation. /off-soap-box

Comment: I am using UTF-8 encoding while sending data from android device @HaigBedrosian

Comment: Ok, that might be contributing to your problem. Can you log your queries and see what data is actually coming through? I think that will give you the hint you need to identify and solve the problem.